# Rails correcting typo errors in records at model level

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails system with existent data entered by the users, and in some cases they made some mistakes creating records twice with similar names.

I'm actually not allowing content duplicates (same name and assignature) maybe this is why it is not working.

I have 2 models :

```
:question
belongs_to :content

:content
has_many :questions
belongs_to assignature
```

What I need to do is to merge 2 records if after updating the name field finds an existing record.

ie.

Content A
name = "This is a test"

Content B 
name = "This is test"

I want to rename Content A to name = "This is test", merge record.questions, and destroy content A.

**Update**

Thanks to @Thomas R. Koll I moved the logic to the controller and things are now working, but I had to make a weird workaround to bypass my uniqueness limitation.

```
contents_controller

def_update

 existent = Content.where(nombre: params[:content][:nombre]).where(assignature_id: params[:content][:assignature_id])
        if existent.present?
            @content.questions.update_all(content_id: existent.first.id)
#if params nombre is equals to existent , model wont update             
params[:content][:nombre] = "dummy"
        end
...

content.rb

after_update :clean_empty_contents

  def clean_empty_contents
    #delete if content has no questions (applies to my system)
    Content.includes(:questions).where(questions: {id: nil}).destroy_all
  end
```

I'm trying with this code without success :

```
content.rb
validates :nombre, uniqueness: { scope: [:assignature_id], :case_sensitive => false}

before_update :correction

  def correction 
    existent = Content.find_by(nombre: self.nombre, assignature: self.assignature).first
    if existent 
        existent.questions = existent.questions + self.questions
        self.destroy
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking from experience, try to be more explicit with your `correction` method and pass to it the object you want to merge with. Why? Because you might happen to be on that object and try to merge with itself. Got it?

And while we are at it, `merge_into!` describes it better than `correction`. Add the ! because you are destroying something.

  `def merge_into!(other)
    # this faster than loading other.questions
    questions.update_all(content_id: other.id)
    # Some safety check would be nice, even better, look into Paranoia.
    self.destroy
  end`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I'm a bit lost about how to implement this, should I use before_update ? and should I pass the id from the controller? Regards

Comment: Pass the object from the controller.

Comment: I'm getting "can't modify frozen hash error", some stackoverflow answers says this is happening because im trying to use a destroyed element. I remove the destroy line and works, questions are re-assigned but screen is not redirecting and element is not being updated even if I declare self.name ="dummy" , will be playing around with this

Comment: Your code just got stranger.  Put the `merge_other!` function into the `Content` model, remove the code from that `update` method in the controller and instead add a new controller member method where you pass the `other_content_id`.
And don't do this `Content.clean_empty_contents`, that's just dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how can I pass other content id if I remove the code that looks for it ? , and self.destroy is not working , its a little hard to follow you without code but I will try to do it. regards

Comment: as i said: add a new controller member method where you pass the other_content_id (to the merge_other! method)

Comment: like this?     def merge_contents
         existent = Content.where(nombre: params[:content][:nombre]).where(assignature_id: params[:content][:assignature_id])
         if existent.present?
              @content.merge_into!(existent.first)
         end
    end

Comment: now works but throws cant modify frozen hash error, I tried butting the destroy line in merge_into! method, and inside the controller method as @content.destroy

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed to point out one important thing: Don't silently destroy data when the user creates data. Always make sure the users knows they are deleting data. I won't answer this question beyond giving you the pointers you need:
1. in the Model have a merge_other!(other_content) method 2. in the controller add an action merge_other and 3. Once a duplicate entry is made, show it to the user and make the click to that merge_other action.